# why dash is used in condition Go templates

Tags: go, kubernetes-helm, go-templates

I've seen many examples of dash being use for if statements ("{{- if.."), e.g:

```
{{- if hasKey .Values.mymap "mykey" }}
    # do something conditional here...
{{- end }}
```

what is the purpose of the dash in that statement?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Dash removes the spaces from the output on the side it appears in the template:

https://golang.org/pkg/text/template/#hdr-Text_and_spaces

```
{{- if ...}}
```

The above will remove all spaces that appear before the if statement, so if the result of `if` prints something, it'll be right after the last piece of text without any spaces.

Comment: in that case, what is the point behind the dash in {{- end }}?

Comment: Removes all spaces after the output of the if body, so the output after {{-end}} now immediately follows the last printed non-space character in the if-body.

Comment: what if move `-` before the closing bracket? does it make any difference?

Comment: @LeiYang, That will remove all spaces after the closing bracket.

Comment: then what's the difference between right dash in first line, and left dash in second line?

Comment: @LeiYang I don't understand the question, but if you look at the link in the answer, it should make things clear.

Comment: i cannot open that link(in china). i mean, `{{ end -}} \n {{ end }} ` vs `{{ end }} \n {{- end }} `  is there any difference, and which is preferable?

Comment: Newline is a space character so both will yield the same result. If it was a different character, the first one will remove the spaces before that character, the second one will remove spaces after.